# What is the most natural way of saying myself

Tags: gramática

While watching a twitch stream someone said:

> yo tengo un Raspberry, que me quiero construir uno

I would of said:

> yo tengo un Raspberry, quiero construir uno yo mismo

The first form of this sentence confuses me a little. I am aware its a relative pronoun but still has me confused.

**Question** - Which is more commonly used?

**Question 2** - What does "que" translate to when used in this form.

Comment: ‘Would *have* said’. ‘Would of’ is grammatically incorrect :-)

Comment: I want to build myself one. is not: I want to build one myself. :)

Answer (score 4):

The two sentences don't mean quite the same:

The first one can be translated as :
**I have a Raspberry, I want to build me one.**

The second one means:
**I have a Raspberry, I want to build one myself**

So only the second sentence is really using "myself" the first one doesn't really use the reflexive.

Comment: I think that's the reason @Kian is confused!

Comment: ‘…I want to build *me* one’ sounds  odd. I would use ‘myself’ (native English speaker)

Comment: I want to "build me" one sounds off but it is used commonly in English. As I mentioned, though, is not the quite the same as saying "myself", its more equivalent to saying: I want to build one for me. The emphasis is not "the builder" but what you want.

Comment: I want to build myself one. is the way to say this.

Answer (score 2):

The original is valid. In this case, ["que" indicates cause](https://blogdeespanol.com/2016/08/que-para-indicar-causa/), which is common in informal speech.

For example: *Déjame tu bolígrafo, que el mío no escribe* = *Let me use your pen, (because) mine is not working*.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, además de "yo mismo", podría usarse la construcción "por mi cuenta". La frase quedaría, pues:

> (...) quiero construir uno por mi cuenta.

---

In this case, in addition to "yo mismo", the construction "por mi cuenta" could be used. The sentence would then be:

> (...) quiero construir uno por mi cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Cuestión:

The first form of this sentence confuses me a little. I am aware its a relative pronoun but still has me confused.

Question 1 - Which is more commonly used?

Question 2 - What does "que" translate to when used in this form.

---

La primera forma de esta oración me confunde un poco. Soy consciente de que es un pronombre relativo, pero todavía me tiene confundido.

Pregunta 1 - ¿Cuál se usa más comúnmente?

**yo tengo un Raspberry, quiero construir uno yo mismo**

Pregunta 2 - ¿Qué significa "que" cuando se usa de esta forma?

**Nada, es un error gramatical, en este caso "que", no es un pronombre relativo, es solo una incorrección - Yo tengo un Raspberry, me quiero construir uno**.